# Entity Framework - Add table by synonyms

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF5 with Oracle Database.

I have a DBlink between two databases where I have permission to write and read specifics tables.

I'ts possible to add this objects as a table im my entity model?

The image bellow is showing my connection:

[image]